# Playing real-time audio in a PC from a microcontroller using naudio

Tags: c#, microcontroller, naudio

I want to connect a microcontroller to PC, and send a wave file form the micro to the PC. I then want to play such wave stream real-time and save it in the PC at the same time.

I can set a connection with USB between the micro and the PC to receive a data array.

I want to play this data array, and transmit the next array in real-time without gaps during playback.

I am using C# to program on the PC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems broad. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is buffering. Since you are using USB and the transfers are not guarenteed in real time, you can start transferring a few seconds "in advance".

On the PC side you can then save the received stream with a thread in charge of enqeueuing the arrays received in a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx).

After enough data arrays are in the queue to allow for your pre-buffering, on a separate thread you want to start retrieving (dequeuing) the data from the Queue, this thread is then in charge of "real time" playback.

The few extra buffers that you use at the beginning will allow you to compensate for temporary lags of data transfer caused by peak demands in other operating system tasks.

If you are transferring your packets usign the concept of URB's, try to make your URB's optimal. Normally URB's of 4K are a good bet for optimal stream data transfer, but if you want to reduce your latency at start, you can reduce the size of these URS's at the expense of suboptimal USB bus utilization.